# Using Joi schemas alongside Mongoose schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, joi

I want to prevent user input to be inserted into the MongoDB.
I want to validate user input properly.

Joi offers a schema based verification in order to test the user input.
Actually sounds good.

Mongoose also have schemas itself, what are the differences?

How about using Joi schema and use [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) plugin instead of Mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The difference between Mongoose's and Joi's schemas

**Mongoose's schemas:** This is where you define the model and the fields it's going to accept

eg.

```
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema ({
  username: String
  email: String
})
const User = mongoose.module("user", UserSchema))
```

Here you're saying that the User model will accept only a username and an email and both are going to be strings.

---

**Joi's schema:** Here you define the validation rules to validate the received data before creating a doc of it. 
eg.

```
const receivedData = {username: "John Doe", email: "doe.john@gmail.com"}
const Joi = require('joi');
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email()
})
const result = Joi.validate(receivedData, schema)
```

So this is how you define the rules with the Joi schema

- `username` field must be a string, alphanum and of length between 3 and 30
- `email` field must be a string and an email

The result will be stored in the `result` constant in a form of an object.

---

And I haven't used `mongojs` before but Joi doesn't relay on Mongoose. so I guess it'll be fine to use `monojs`.

Comment: You explained the difference, but is there a reason to use both (I've seen a couple of examples where both were used to validate user input)?

Comment: The reason to use both - **validation on the specific level**. With provided by mongoose model scheme validation we can validate data at the **application level**, so right before persisting it to the database. With Joi we can validate data at the **request level**. So we don't go as far as to data persisting, but we stop before that, before the logic of putting the request object into db.